# How do I prove $\{ x : Ax=b \}$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, locally-convex-spaces

I have a constraint $Ax=b$, where $A$ is $m\times n$, b is $m\times1$. I am wondering how should I prove that $\{ x  \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid  Ax=b \}$ is convex.

Attempt:

$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax=b\}$ is convex because:

$Ax_1=b, Ax_2=b \; \Rightarrow \; A(tx_1 +(1−t)x_2) = tAx_1 +(1−t)Ax_2 = (t+1−t)b = b$.

Comment: What is a convex equality?

Comment: I modify my question

Comment: It's a correct proof.

Comment: If the mapping is defined as $x\mapsto Ax$, then you are _halfway_ there. Note that $A x_1=y_1$ and $A x_2=y_2$. It seems you can do the rest

Comment: @polfosol I think he wants to prove convexity of a set, not of a function. The current proof is correct for that